# jQuery UI Selectable, can't access items during selecting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've got some piece of code with jQuery UI Selectable implementation. Just like this:

```
$(wrapper).selectable({
  selecting: function(event, ui){
    // some work with items
  }
});
```

In UI documentation I found words about accessing items that was selected *during selection process* (it's very important). But I can't do this through *ui.item* object despite the fact that I can do this for example with Sortable UI module.
Please, if you have deal with this unusual behavior of jQuery UI write couple words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, that's resolved. You can operate with *ui.selecting* object during selection process. As example to get id of just selected element you must operate with *ui.selecting.id*.